# Unable to access, make directories (and files) with ftp

Tags: ftp, centos5

I'm having trouble with my new server and accessing its directories.

I updated my `proftpd.conf` with:

```
DefaultRoot /
```

No I'm able to see the root directory of my server. **But, trying to access some directories gives different results.**

For example, I can access `/vars` but I can't access `/home` or `/root`

**How can I overcome this?**

---

This is what my ftp client says after trying to access `/root`:

```
Server said: /root: No such file or directory

Error -125: remote chdir failed
```

---

This is what my ftp client says after trying to create a new directory in `/`:

```
Server said: untitled folder: Permission denied

Error -140: remote mkdir failed
```

Comment: What privileges does the account you're logging in with have?

Comment: @Yitzchak - How can I check that?

Comment: ls -l on the files you want to edit. Check the user block for your rights on that file. If you are ftp-ing in as anything but root (btw ftp as root is a *bad* idea) you will not be able to make a new directory in /

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, use sftp in the future.

Comment: I will definitely do that!

Comment: btw, if you'd like, perhaps you could answer this question so Ic an approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ls -l on the files you want to edit. Check the user block for your rights on that file. If you are ftp-ing in as anything but root (btw ftp as root is a bad idea) you will not be able to make a new directory in /

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using client with fish protocol support instead, big chances are you have sshd started on your new server. Anyway, configuring system-wide FTP access for all partitions sounds not so good for me, I'd rather use it for isolated environment.

Comment: I'm aware it's not the best idea. I'm trying to comprehend the possibilities. (read: basic stuff)